# The fastest way to obtain orientation θ from this ellipse formula?

Tags: algorithms, conic-sections

In this rotating ellipse formula: $A(x − h)^2 + B(x − h)(y − k) + C(y − k)^2 = 1$

Suppose I have $A,B,C,h,k$ parameters, and I want to obtain the angle $θ$ from the centroid $(h,k)$ to the horizontal axis, at the red dot in this image:

[image: ellipse]

There are two things I am concerning:

1. Acquiring $θ$: I got the inverse tangent in my mind. If I can get the $(x',y')$ of the red dot, then this should be simple. However, before doing that, I am curious about the fastest way possible to calculate $θ$ in this case. If we have $A,B,C,h,k,$ what would be the fastest way to obtain $θ$?
2. Due to the nature of an ellipse, both ends of each axis are the same. This implies $0$ degrees and $180$ degrees will look exactly the same visually, however, if possible, I would like to obtain this difference as well. Currently I do not know whether from the rotating formula above, can we obtain the whole $360$ degrees orientation, or only $0-180$? Can somebody please clear this?

Comment: I think, Israel's last answer could inspire you well for this setp. Nice point of view.+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$h$ and $k$ don't matter.  It looks like the red dot is on the major axis.  So this is the angle $\theta$ of my answer to your last question.  If $B \ne 0$,
$$ \theta = \arctan \left(\dfrac{C-A + \sqrt{(C-A)^2 + B^2}}{B} \right)$$

I'm not sure what you mean by your second question.  What difference do you want to obtain if there is no difference?  The  formula above gives the $\theta$ that is in the interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ in radians, or $(-90, 90)$ in degrees.

Comment: I see. I was wondering whether I can get 0-360 degrees. But I see that from your answer, $\theta$ will be in interval (-90,90) in degrees. Also, from my current understanding, your formula will always be pointing at the major axis, right?

Comment: Yes, and yes.  If you want an angle in a different range, you can always add 180 or 360 degrees.  If you want the minor axis, add or subtract 90 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Let me tackle your second question. I'll put it in this order:

> I do not  know whether from the rotating formula above, can
> we obtain the whole 360 degrees orientation.
>
> [H]owever, if possible, I would like to obtain this difference as well.

First- *No*.  Your formula does not distinguish positions 180° apart. This is a property of the formula, not the ellipse.

Second-- *Yes* it is possible.  I see you have marked one end with a red dot.  That'll do nicely. The trick is to measure in a way that preserves this difference.  The following steps are fleshed out with working examples in

[this Geogebra worksheet](http://www.geogebratube.org/material/show/id/45026)

**1.** Correction: Mr. Israel's formula gives the *minor* axis.  For the Major, change the square root to negative.  Below, I use $atan(-)$ and $atan(+)$  to mean "use Mr. Israel's formula, and take the negative (or positive) root."

**2.** In geometry, we give direction and orientation directly on the figure.  In algebra, we use signed values.  Here, the (pair of) equation(s)

$$Ax^2 + B x y + Cy^2 = ±1$$

are an ellipse when
   a)$B^2 - 4AC < 0$, and
    b) A, C,  ±1 all have the same sign.
If you use  $Ax^2 + B x y + Cy^2 = 1$, you must also restrict $A, C > 0$.
atan(+) gives the major axis of  the conjugate ellipse, $Ax^2 + B x y + Cy^2 = -1$.

**3.** atan(+), and atan(-) are 90° apart.  When one jumps between ±π/2, the other crosses smoothly over 0. If we measure the *difference* between two nearby angles, one of the two changes of atan() will be continuous. This is

SOLUTION 1 - BLUE:  Start with an initial position. Let $θ_0 =atan_0 (-).\;\;$, defining a point $P$ on the major axis in the range -90° < θ <90°. Rotate the ellipse by a small amount (change A, B C). Call the new position $θ_1$. To find it, calculate the change in angle: 
   $dθ = atan_1  - atan_0$
  $θ_1 = θ_0 + dθ$

When atan(-) falls out of range, dθ leaps suddenly. Go back one step and use atan(+) (which will be in range) to measure dθ.  When atan(+) jumps, go back to (-)... etc. Always use two consecutive values of the *same* function to calculate dθ.  Now you can track θ over the full 360°.   Since you're only using the change in angle, it doesn't matter if atan() is close to θ.

The worksheet follows the same principle, but I just use atan(-).

**4.**  If I account for all points in this way, the BLUE solution always works.
However, the ellipse $Ax^2 + B x y + Cy^2 = 1$ passing through $P$ is still *discontinous under rotation*.  This is the

GREEN PROBLEM: I have drawn two ellipses.  Both correctly track P over the full 360°.  Geogebra uses your formula, then maps it to a path.  This does not work. The Dot family is distributed at even intervals along a section of the arc. If you rotate the ellipse (point $Q$), they have a turbulent future.
The problem is this:

**5.** All motion is differential. Let me restate this observation slightly:

> I'm not sure what you mean by your second question. What difference do
> you want to obtain if there is no difference?

I prefer: *This equation is unorientable*. One answer is to select a different representation.  This is

**6.**  SOLUTION 2 - BLACK: Point $P = r(t) = (x(t), y(t)),$ moves over time, beginning on the major axis (t=0). As t increases, it smoothly traverse the arc until it returns home (t= 2π). The unrotated ellipse is:
$$r(t) = (a \cos t, b \sin t)$$

To rotate r(t), use the unit vector in the direction θ: $\vec e_θ = (\cos θ, \sin θ)$.   The rotated ellipse is:
$$r_2(t)= \begin{bmatrix}{} \cos θ & -\sin θ \\ \sin θ & \cos θ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}{} a\cos t \\ b\sin t \end{bmatrix} $$
$$ = (a\cos θ \cos t - b\sin θ \sin t, \;\;a\sin θ \cos t + b\cos θ \sin t)$$

You can check by hand that, given an arbitrary point $r(t_0) = (x_0, y_0)$, the corresponding point $r_2(t_0)$ is rotated about the origin by θ.  The matrix on the left is a rotation matrix.

The worksheet includes more steps, and alternate notation. Hopefully this is enough information to make the solution accessible, even if the notation is unfamiliar.  I didn't use abstract notation because I like being abstract.  In this case, *it solves the problem*:  The Dot family is continuous, you can correctly relate points on the arc, and finding the rotation & measurements of the ellipse is faster and easier: you give them *directly*.

Hope that helps.  As always, let me know if anything is confusing so I can make it better (more useful to you).