# Parametric Coordinates of an Ellipse through skewed Cartesian coordinates

Tags: trigonometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

I wanted to find parametric coordinates of an ellipse purely in terms of trigonometric functions. For this I began with finding counterparts of $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions in skewed Cartesian coordinates and termed them as g(x) and f(x), respectively. Since $\cos(x),\sin(x)$ are the parametric coordinates of circle, I expected an ellipse upon plugging in $(f(x),g(x))$. With the help of Sine rule I  established (here $\phi$ is the acute angle Y-axis makes with X-axis)
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(\phi-\theta)}{\sin(\phi)}
$$
$$
g(x)=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sin(\phi)}
$$
[image]
I did receive an ellipse as output, but with the major axis aligned to the line $y=x$ or $y=-x$ for all values of $\phi$, in contrast I expected it align with the line $y=\tan(\phi)$.I would like to know why this happened and  what manipulation would correct it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what kind of reasoning you made to write those equations, but you might have been misled by the circumstance that the parameter $\theta$ in the parametric equations of an ellipse is not the same as the polar angle. Better then to use letter $t$ to represent that parameter.

In general, any parametric equation of the form
$$\vec p(t)=\vec\alpha\cos t+\vec\beta\sin t,$$
where  $\vec\alpha$ and $\vec\beta$ are two constant vectors,
represents an ellipse centred at the origin, having
$\vec\alpha$ and $\vec\beta$ as [conjugate semi-diameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_diameters).

Your equations are of that kind, with
$$
\alpha=(1, 0),\quad \beta=(-\cot\phi, \csc\phi)
$$
and that explains why they lead to an ellipse.
On the other hand, that ellipse passes through
$(\pm1,0)$ and $(0,\pm1)$
and that means, by symmetry, that the axes of the ellipse
are the lines bisecting the quadrants.

This can also be found from the values of $t$ leading to the vertices of the ellipse, [which can be computed from](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617870/sketching-an-arbitrary-ellipse-from-its-parametric-equation/4618168#4618168):

$$
\tan 2t={2\vec\alpha\cdot\vec\beta
\over|\vec\alpha|^2-|\vec\beta|^2}=\tan\phi,
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
t={\phi\over2},\quad t={\phi+\pi\over2}.
$$
Plugging this into your equations one gets in fact $y(t)=\pm x(t)$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What I did was to consider a coordinate system with [non orthogonal coordinate axes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_coordinates#Cartesian_coordinates_with_one_skewed_axis), than I took a unit vector from origin, and found an equivalent of Sin and Cos by putting $f(x)=\frac{a}{1}$ and $g(x)=\frac{b}{1}$ where a and b are projections of unit vector upon x axes and y axes, respectively. I applied sine rule upon the so formed triangle and defined f(x) and g(x) in terms of Sin. I expected them to yield an ellipse in normal Cartesian system